In Entity Framework how should I limit string length to no greater than 12000 characters
I tried the obvious...
[StringLength(12000)]
public string Instructions { get; set; }

...(also tried MaxLength) but when I run add-migration I get empty Up() and Down() methods. The only impact of adding the migration is this in the Snapshot file...
...
b.Property<string>("Instructions")
.HasMaxLength(12000)
.HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)")
...

...the .HasMaxLength(12000) gets added - that's it, and it has no effect - I can save values in excess of 12000 characters.
So what would be the right way to validate/limit this property to have no more than 12000 characters?!
Thanks

This is Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.6, and SQL Server 2022. Thanks.

FYI, nvarchar has max length 4000. Probably EF Core used for migration only name of type nvarchar(max), which means - no difference for migration.

Thanks. Right - it makes sense that the datatype doesn't change since 4000 = max, but I still want an exception thrown if an attempt is made to enter > 12,000 characters. Thanks again!

Try remove HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)") maybe then you will see exception.

Thanks, but that's in the auto generated ModelSnapShot file, and I don't want to mess with that.

Got this from the EF Core team...
“EF Core does not do validation for you. EF6 had some validation, but it was rarely used and duplicated the validation already done by applications elsewhere. So EF uses the string length for database creation and for efficient parameter creation, but makes no attempt to validate your data for you.”
